# I have to change recersuvely a number several txt files on Linux or Windows

Tags: recursion, substitution, txt

I have got about 500 text files with corrupted data, where numbers like -100, -101,..,-800  should be changed with the string E-99. The negative numbers I have to replace have maximum with three digits, i.e. -123 and not -1234.

To be more specific. Ideally the script should check in every text file if any negative number from -999 to -100 is present and if yes substitute it with E-99. This is an example of the problem:

```
  0.1808611111111111E+01   0.7528113587914270E+00   0.1001507858301227E-99   0.6020088060784779E-98

  0.1808750000000000E+01   0.7528113587914270E+00   0.9843386354523974-100   0.5916883445235866E-98
```

The model messes up with notation smaller than E-99. It does not write E-100 but deadly -100 and that is also valid for E-200 , E-201, E-202 and so forth that are changed with -200, 201, 202. There are other thousands of data like this, divided in 4 columns.

How can i do that from command line or with a bash/windows scrip?

I only found solutions where a precise string is replaced with another specific string. However I need to change all negative numbers with up to three digit

Comment: Please edit question with sample data.  In particular what comes after those numbers?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So if a line ends with -100 to -999 replace it with E-99?

Comment: Yes, correctly. I need to restore the exponential notation.

Comment: At the end I manged to do that in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to change your txt files inline:

```
$ sed -i 's/-\([1-9][0-9][0-9]\)\($\| \+\)/E-99\2/g' *.txt
```

Comment: I tried your `sed` solution with a single column of data and that actually worked. But when I add three more columns, so four columns in total as per my file, it does not change the values unfortunately.

Comment: Update question with representative sample data.  You need to replace $ with \\($\\|something\\) but I don't know what the column separator is and use \2 in the replacement so you don't lose that data.

Comment: I tried `sed -i 's/-\([1-9][0-9][0-9]\)\($\\2\)/E-99/'` in a representative file which reproduces the big file I have but still not the expected results.

Comment: I updated the regex to match the revised format.  I used ' \+' instead of '\s\+' in case that is what trips you up.

Comment: That works thank you! Where can I report this answer as the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Allan Wind's answer, you need to:

1. use 'g' for global replacement like sed 's/pattern to find/pattern to replace/g'. This would replace 'all' matching patterns.
2. instead of "$" use \s+ (means match one or more spaces).

So the command would be "sed 's/-([1-9][0-9][0-9])\s+/E-99/g'".
Please note that -i flag would change files in-place. I would suggest that instead of changing files in-place it is better to redirect output of sed to another file so that original data is preserved. You can create a script like:

#! /bin/sh

for i in `ls *.txt`; do

```
    sed 's/-\([1-9][0-9][0-9]\)\s+/E-99/g' $i > new_$i
```

done

don't forget to modify above script to use appropriate file-path instead of "*.txt"
This will create new_<input_filename> file for each <input_file>

after you get the output, you could easily use diff command to check differences between original and modified files.

PS: Not enough SO credits to post comments for me yet.

Comment: Hi Dilip, thanks a lot for your help unfortunately it does not work. I will check more carefully.